# 英語が残っている箇所: 編集リクエスト送信後のアラート This edit will be visible only to you until it is peer reviewed

Tags: バグ, 完了, 翻訳, 英語

[image: This edit will be visible only to you until it is peer reviewed.]

Comment: 翻訳を登録しました。次回のビルドで適用します。

Answer (score 2):

> ピアレビューで承認されるまで、編集した内容はあなたにしか見えません。